# Composer could not find a composer.json file in /composer/bin/

Tags: laravel, composer-php, cpanel, whm

I use cpanel/WHM on my web server but when I try to run composer install in my laravel project, its showing error like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this first:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Set+Up+%28PHP%29+Composer

I think it provides all the answers you need. Oh, one more thing, try running composer as a cpanel user and not as root. It's even stating that and you can read why you should not run composer as root on their webpage